# Difficulty to download GHDL with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu

Good evening,

I wanted to download GHDL so I did this command :

> sudo apt-get install ghdl

But I have a message who said that no version of the GHDL package is disponible [available — translated spanish/french to english], but that it exists in the database. And they said that the package GHDL doesn't have a version who can be installed.

I try this command too :

> sudo apt-get install ghdl gtkwave

But I get the same message. So, my question is : how can I download GHDL? I'm on Ubuntu, with the 16.04 version.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When was the last time you run `apt update`?

Comment: Can you show the error message in the question.

Comment: I install Ubuntu last week and did the update. But in case I did it now and nothing change. The error is in French, but I can put it here (but now I did the instruction from the other answer below and the error change a little bit) :

Comment: `Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
ghdl is already the newest version (0.33-1ubuntu1).
Vous pouvez lancer « apt-get -f install » pour corriger ces problèmes :
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 ghdl : Dépend: libgnat-4.8 (>= 4.8.2-8ubuntu3) mais il n'est pas installable
E: Dépendances non satisfaites. Essayez « apt-get -f install » sans paquet
(ou indiquez une solution).`

Answer (score 2):

Another way of installing GHDL on your Ubuntu is to download the package manually and install it using the `dpkg` command. Here is how you can do this:

Go to: https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases/tag/v0.33

Download the `ghdl_0.33-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb` package directly onto your Ubuntu by executing the following command:

`wget https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases/download/v0.33/ghdl_0.33-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

After it finished downloading, you can execute the following command to install it:

`sudo dpkg --install ghdl_0.33-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

Comment: I did the first command and it was okay, but with the second they said that the  package libgnat-4.8 isn't install. So I did

`sudo apt-get install libgnat-4.8`

But I meet the same error that for downloading ghdl : that no version of this package is disponible. This package is important?

Comment: @Hix Looks like that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is corrupted. Can you copy/paste the content of that file here?

Comment: There is juste a file for skype inside (skye-stable.list) and inside this file its written :
`deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main`
but I don't think that it was the thing that you speak about

Comment: @Hix Take a look at this [link](http://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/etc-apt-sources-list-ubuntu-16-xenial/). It will show you what should be in the `\etc\apt\sources.list` file. Once you did that, make sure you run `sudo apt update` and then try installing the package you want.

Comment: It didn't work, but I find that dowload gnat fixed all ... I don't understand why but it works ! Thanks for helping !

Comment: (I don't know how to close the topic, but the question is solved)

Comment: @Hix you can answer you own question explaining what you did to solve it and then accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Katu I'm sorry, I'm new there and I didn't find a way to solve my problem.